# Methods signature got changed while compiling the gradle java application and referencing to other project

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, micronaut, micronaut-rest

I have two projects known as (`Common` and `ApiGateway`).The common is a Gradle java project and ApiGateway is a Micronaut java application. In the common project, I am keeping all the common things and referencing the jar to the Apigateway project.

**Common project**

The below code is compiled with `./gradlew build`

```
@Validated
public interface IProductOperation {
    @Get(value = "/search/{text}")
    @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
    Flux<?> freeTextSearch(@NotBlank String text);


    @Get(value = "/{?searchCriteria*}")
    @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
    Mono<?> find(FilterProductModel searchCriteria);
}
```

The **API gateway** implements the `IProductOperation` interface which is in the **common project**. When I navigate to the **code base**, I can see the below code is generated

```
@Validated
public interface IProductOperation {

    @Get("/search/{text}")
    @Secured({"isAnonymous()"})
    Flux<?> freeTextSearch(@NotBlank String var1);


    @Get("/{?searchCriteria*}")
    @Secured({"isAnonymous()"})
    Mono<?> find(FilterProductModel var1);

}
```

Now when I compile the second application the **Apigateway** project, I get an exception as `The route declares a uri variable named [text], but no corresponding method argument is present` which is valid because the parameter in `freeTextSearch()` and `find()` methods got changed to `var1`.

I have below dependency in the common project

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java:3.5.0"
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation:3.5.0"

    implementation('io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.2.0')
    implementation 'io.micronaut:micronaut-core:3.5.0'

    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject:3.5.0"
    implementation 'io.micronaut:micronaut-validation:3.5.0'
    implementation ('io.micronaut.reactor:micronaut-reactor:2.2.2')
    implementation("io.micronaut.security:micronaut-security-jwt:3.6.0")
}
```

I have build the application and publish to local mavel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation has a section about retaining parameter names https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#retainparameternames